# How to disable the controls in an ASP.NET page when the usercontrol is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I Successfully created an user control for displaying Error message. now everything works fine but when the message is shown the background controls can be accessed. how to disable the page controls or page from clicking or selecting any controls. and when the message panel is closed it should enable the page controls.

i found the answer friends.

```
void DisableControls(Control parent, bool status)
    {
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (c is DropDownList)
                {
                    ((DropDownList)(c)).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    ((Button)(c)).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)c).Enabled = status;
                }

                if (c is RadioButton)
                {
                    ((RadioButton)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is ImageButton)
                {
                    ((ImageButton)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is CheckBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is DropDownList)
                {
                    ((DropDownList)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is HyperLink)
                {
                    ((HyperLink)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is GridView)
                {
                    ((GridView)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is Table)
                {
                    ((Table)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is Menu)
                {
                    ((Menu)c).Enabled = status;
                }
                if (c is TreeView)
                {
                        ((TreeView)c).Enabled = status;
                    } 
}
        }
```

Comment: when the user control is activated i got the div in which i have added the controls.but the controls in the page from where i called is also active. i want to disable the controls in that page.

Comment: I think you'll find that you can simplify your code *greatly* by simply using the following: `foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {  c.Enabled = false; }`  because Enabled is a property of `Control`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried that already but cant do it sucessfully. it throws an error.

Comment: its illegal to say it throws an error without saying what error it is :)

Comment: A modal div is a much better solution. Also, your solution can be simplified by checking that the control is a WebControl rather than casting from all of the derived classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, you want it to behave like a modal dialog. It can be done via simple html + javascript.
You must create a transparent div overlay that goes over the whole page, so the user instead of clicking the controls it would be clicking on the div. Z-index indicates the position over the rest of controls.

```
<!-- Div Overlay -->
<div id="div-overlay" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 200; display: none; opacity: 0.0"></div>

<!-- Scripts to show/hide overlay -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOverlay() {
    var e = document.getElementById('div-overlay');
    e.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOverlay() {
    var e = document.getElementById('div-overlay');
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply a div and with the help of CSS, you can able to display that div like a modal popup or simply use jquery modal popup http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ or asp.net ajaxcontrol toolkit http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Comment: no i don't want to use ajax in this because i got some problems like page flickering and etc.

Comment: Use JQuery if you can or just simply use CSS to display like a modal popup and then all other controls will not be accessible

Comment: just for an hint you can do like this <style type="text/css">
         .modalBackground
    {
        background-color: #7A7A7A;
        filter: alpha(opacity=90);
        position: -1000px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }    
    .ModalWindow
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        bottom: 1230px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: Black;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a modal dialog? If yes you can use the ModalPopupExtender Control from asp.net ajax. check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164247.aspx

Comment: Did you try using this control? I don't think you will get any issues like page flickering.

Comment: When the page reloads or refreshes the model popup just comes and goes for some milli seconds